# Out of power connectors, need to install 3 more drives

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, sata

I just built a new PC. My motherboard (Gigabyte Z77) has 8 SATA connectors.

The problem is, I have run out of power supply connectors! I need to install 3 more drives.

How can I increase the number of power connectors?

Comment: Make sure your new power supply has enough watts to cover the power requirements for all those drives.

Comment: -1 no research effort on your part.

Comment: @BonGart How do you know there was no research on my part? Sometimes if your not familiar with a subject you dont even know what to google!! Now I know I am looking for Molex to sata adapters and also that i need to chekc if my power supply is good enough.I would not have thought of that

Comment: @ultrasawblade Very good point! Didnt think of that.Looked at the instructions for my cx 430 corsair and could not see what it support.How do you know whether it can support so many drives?

Comment: http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp - you can use that to calculate the total watts needed by your system.  Estimate about 20W per drive.  Instructions or label on PSU should tell you total continuous watts it can handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any unused [Molex power connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector#Disk_drive_connector_.28Molex_8981_Series_Power_Connector.29)? If so, there are inexpensive Molex-to-Sata [adapters](http://www.google.com/search?q=molex%20to%20sata)  that you can use; they come in "splitter" flavor as well (giving you two Sata connectors from one Molex).

And of course there are also Sata power splitters; a Google search gives results such as [this](http://www.cooldrives.com/sapoyca15sap.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are power supplies with 8 SATA connectors; 5 minutes Newegging turned up [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817139020650W) Corsair power supply.